# Incorrect graphics card information

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I have an HP-B021AX laptop with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. According to [HP's website](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c05221023), it has **AMD Radeon™ R7 M440 Graphics**, but on doing `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'` I get

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Carrizo (rev ca)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 81fa
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
--
06:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 81fa
    Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
```

Under "About This Computer" or All Settings->Details, it shows AMD Radeon (TM) R7 M340.

Why is it displaying R7 M260/M265 or R7 M340 instead of R7 M440?

Comment: perhaps because you have an R7 M260/M265

Comment: @ravery Under All Settings->Details it says, AMD Radeon (TM) R7 M340.